# How do you find the contours in an image and resize it python3?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, contour

I tried to simulate the mnist dataset by finding the contours(numbers) available and making the numbers grayscale and (28,28) but it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
num_pic = cv2.cvtColor(num_pic, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, imgth = cv2.threshold(num_pic, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

cv2.imshow('img window', imgth)
cv2.waitKey()

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgth.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
c = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in contours]
print(c)
c = cv2.resize(c, (28,28))
cv2.imshow('img window', c[0])
cv2.waitKey()

print(count)
res = []
for rect in c:
    cv2.rectangle(num_pic, (rect[0]-10,rect[1]-10),(rect[0]+rect[2]+10, rect[1]+rect[3]+10), (0,255,0),3)
    roi = imgth[rect[1]-10:rect[1]+rect[3]+10,rect[0]-10:rect[0]+rect[2]+10]
    print(roi.shape)
    roi = cv2.resize(roi, (28,28))
    res.append(roi)
count +=1
cv2.imshow('img window', roi[0])
cv2.waitKey()
exit()
```

this is my image of numbers which I work on:
[image]
**sorry it is a little big!

This may seem simple but I have ran into many almost impossible to conquer errors. I just gave up after this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "logisticregressionMNIST.py", line 84, in <module>
    roi = cv2.resize(roi, (28,28))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

How do I solve this error? 
Also, how do I do this task of finding the contours in an image and making it grayscale and (28,28)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this code is that cv2.resize() accepts 2 value, the 1st one is an image you want to resize, and the second one is the size to which you want to resize the image.

In your code, you are passing "c" in cv2.resize() in place of the image where "c" is list of tuples, it is not an image that is causing the error.

To get the digits from the image and resize them to (28, 28), use this code after thresholding input image and storing it in "imgth" -

```
# removing noise from the image - important step
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), dtype = np.uint8)
imgth = cv2.dilate(imgth, kernel, iterations = 5)
imgth = cv2.erode(imgth, kernel, iterations = 5)

# Finding contours and their bounding rectangle(same as your code).
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgth.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
c = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in contours]

# For each bounding rectangle, crop that rectangle from the image and resize it and store these images in "crI"
crI = []
for i in range(len(c)):
    cr = cv2.resize(imgth[c[i][1]:c[i][1]+c[i][3], c[i][0]:c[i][0]+c[i][2]], (28,28))
    crI.append(cr)
```

The variable "crI" will contain all the digit images of size (28, 28) in a list.